# Trying to get ethernet working for Intel 82562EZ 10/100.

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I got an old Dell Dimension 4600 for free and I want to get Linux on it. Ubuntu not required, but it's what I have running now.

lspci -v tells me:

```
Ethernet Controller: Intel Corporation 82562EZ 10/100 Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell Device 0174
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 20
Memory at fbfff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
I/O port sat df40 [size=64]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kerneldriver in use: e100
```

This is without modifying anything. I'm surprised the driver that came with Ubuntu didn't work.

Intel provides a Linux driver here:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=2896&agr=Y

But when I try to `make install` I get an error, which is addressed in the README:

```
Driver Compilation
  ------------------

  When trying to compile the driver by running make install, the following
  error may occur:

      "Linux kernel source not configured - missing version.h"

  To solve this issue, create the version.h file by going to the Linux
  source tree and entering:

      make include/linux/version.h.
```

What do they mean go to the Linux source tree? I didn't get an /include/ directory in the tarball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a problem that is not related to the driver. I didn't have a router in my network, only a modem. So my ISP was probably limiting my IP addresses (not giving my Dell one). I am going to look into getting a router.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the package names linux-build-essentials, but that may be not required:  There's a link at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/if_fxp.4freebsd.html which discusses your network card and how to install it.  I would also suggest that you load the package linux-firmware-nonfree

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`